# Heywood Case in Exploratory Factor Analysis (in R)

Tags: r, factor-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I am running an EFA in R using the `psych` package and am getting a warning that there's a Heywood case with the following code:

```
model = fa(data, nfactors = 3, rotate = "oblimin", fm = "ml")
```

However, I can't seem to figure out where the Heywood case is based on my output. Any help is appreciated!

[image: R Output]

Answer (score 2):

You will need to look at the standardized solution. In that output, you should have an estimate for the variance for the items in the model. One of them has been flagged as having an impossible variance.

Alternatively, if you sum the squares of the standardized factor loadings, one of the items will have a sum that exceeds 1.  This is your culprit.